# File can't run while being uploaded simultaneously via FTP

Tags: php, linux, apache, ftp, centos

Not sure if this is server related or normal behavior, but I thought I'd ask. I run a relatively high-traffic website (200k+ uniques/week) and we serve lots of links through a PHP file containing redirects.

The only problem is, I need to update this file frequently, which I do via SFTP. The file is around 800k in size and takes a second or so to download. However, users have informed me that sometimes the links redirected through the PHP file don't work, and I've realized that this only happens when I'm uploading or downloading the file via SFTP.

So my question is: **Is there any way I can keep the file executable for users while I upload new copies of it via FTP?** This downtime is bothersome for my users. Is this some setting in Linux that I'm not aware of, or is there nothing I can do about this? If it makes a difference, my server is running Centos.

Comment: Upload using a different filename and then create some PHP script (secured) that deletes the old file and renames the new file to the correct name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upload it as a different filename, and then rename it to clobber the old one.  The upload takes significant time (if anything beyond 'instantaneous' is significant).  rename (or mv) is atomic and won't make your users wait.  You could take as much time as you need uploading the file, and then in a split second rename it.

Comment: @DavidO Symlinks man.. sym links. "a split" second to you is fast, but renaming a file or replacing a file with mv is going to be like dramatically slower than using symlinks.

Comment: I saw your post.  I was about to follow up to it with a comment asking for some documentation.  It's not that I don't believe you.  You may be correct.  I'm looking for somewhere I can find enlightenment. :)

Comment: @DavidO Think about it. Have you ever mv'ed a lot of files from one directory to another? Or have you ever over written a bunch of files from one directory to another? It takes more than a few seconds. You think because it's only one file it's going to be instantaneous some how? That's not rational. symlinks are like pointers in programming or references, it's like an address pointer.

Comment: @DavidO You're dispensing bad advice.

Comment: @FinalForm: Show me where to find documentation that the atomic operation of mv is slower than the atomic operation of manipulating a symlink.  I'm not challenging your assertion, I'm asking where I can find a thorough and definitive treatment on the topic.  I wouldn't call an atomic solution bad advice.  You may have a better solution, please show me where I can learn why it's better.  Filling up the thread with comments promoting your solution over others without providing a source to document why it's better doesn't help people to see why it works better.

Comment: @DavidO K, let me find you documentation.

Comment: @DavidO K, I was wrong http://www.itgalary.com/printer_friendly_posts.asp?TID=132

Comment: You might find `man mv(1)` and `man rename(2)` useful.  The last thing I expected was that you would think files were actually being moved, but it appears from your link that's what you were expecting.  By the way, `time mv this that` versus `time ln -s that newlink` showed ln -s to be about 3x slower on my system in a run of 1000 operations.

Comment: @DavidO K, I'm removing my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Will go with renaming then.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the file transfer is not atomic. It rewrites the file as its being uploaded. Which causes the file to be incomplete if the file is downloaded in the meantime.

If you upload the file into another location and then move the file into its correct location after the upload is complete you will replace the file atomically.

Comment: mv is atomic and basically instant for a single file unless you are moving the file to another physical volume. The file data itself does not move, only the file system pointing to the data changes.

Comment: @datasage NOT unless you're overwriting a file. :-/

Comment: @FinalForm What happens is the file descriptor is moved from one set of clusters to another. The data itself is not rewritten on the disk.

Comment: @datasage k, i was wrong. http://www.itgalary.com/printer_friendly_posts.asp?TID=132

Answer (score 1):

Pmivdb actually has it. Upload it at a temp file, then rename it (make sure to keep a copy of the old one). That is really your best (only?) option.

Answer (score 1):

if you put the files in a separate folder and increment the file names is there some php script which would use the latest file???